Redirect Urls not working for dynamic URLs in Aura community
Hello,
We will soon release a new version of a portal site with a new URL and to prepare correctly, we would like to set redirect Urls in Salesforce by using the "URL Redirects" menu on the community.
The current community uses the Aura framework and the new community uses the LWR framework.
It works well for static URLs but it doesn't work for dynamic URLs.
I read the documentation and I understand we can't set URL redirects for dynamic URLS like a page for a specific product (/s/product/detail/1234567890654).
Is there a workaround for my usecase or is it impossible (redirect a dynamic URL to the home page of the community)?
Thanks

Out of the box - no. The workaround is creating your own "router" (custom code) component that does what you want.

Thank you for your confirmation.
